# Как на JS сделать сумму чекбоксов?

Tags: javascript

Дан код на странице?

```
<div class="block">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="one">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="two">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="three">
  <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="four">
</div>
```

Как мне произвести вычисления и получить сумму value (ответ 10) и знать сколько чекбоксов при этом выбрано всего (в данном случае 4).
Имя поля не принципиально, можно сделать у всех name="box[]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всем чекбоксам сделай один name="cname"

```
var sum = 0;
var elements = tableElem.getElementsByName('cname');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
var input = elements[i];
sum = sum + input.value;
alert( input.value + ': ' + input.checked );
}
```

elements.length - кол-во чекбоксов

sum  - сумма

Comment: Ваш код не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант, без указания имени и других атрибутов, что по моему мнению **более правильно**, и возвращает сумму *числом*.

```
var summ = 0;

for (var i = 0; i<document.getElementsByTagName ("input").length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName ("input")[i].type == "checkbox") {
        var num = parseInt (document.getElementsByTagName ("input")[i].value)
        summ += num;

        if (i==document.getElementsByTagName ("input").length-1) {
            alert (summ);
        };
  };
};
```